# Ionic Http request getting error with XML object

Tags: javascript, xml, http, ionic4, geoserver

I've a problem when I try to send an XML object to Geoserver.
When I try with Postman it sends successfully, even in Geoserver Demo.
But with my emulator I get these errors.

I've tried HTTPClient, XMLHttpRequest and HTTP from `'@ionic-native/http/ngx';` but I don't get a good feedback.

With XMLHttpRequest and HttpClient I get this error:

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://ip_address:port/geoserver/worksapce/wfs' from origin 'http://localhost' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

And with HTTP from `'@ionic-native/http/ngx';` I get this one

> Error: advanced-http: "data" option is configured to support only following data types: Object at Object.processData (helpers.js:400)
>   at Object.sendRequest (public-interface.js:158)
>   at Object.post (public-interface.js:174)
>   at callCordovaPlugin (vendor-es2015.js:98821)
>   at vendor-es2015.js:98636
>   at vendor-es2015.js:98594
>   at new ZoneAwarePromise (polyfills-es2015.js:3882)
>   at tryNativePromise (vendor-es2015.js:98593)
>   at getPromise (vendor-es2015.js:98614)
>   at wrapPromise (vendor-es2015.js:98619)

Here is my code

```
 var xmlData= '<wfs:Transaction service="WFS" version="1.0.0" '+
   'xmlns:topp="http://www.openplans.org/topp" '+
   'xmlns:ogc="http://www.opengis.net/ogc" '+
   'xmlns:wfs="http://www.opengis.net/wfs">'+
   '<wfs:Update typeName="topp:tasmania_roads">'+
     '<wfs:Property>'+
      '<wfs:Name>TYPE</wfs:Name>'+
      '<wfs:Value>street</wfs:Value>'+
    '</wfs:Property>'+
    '<ogc:Filter>'+
      '<ogc:FeatureId fid="tasmania_roads.1"/>'+
    '</ogc:Filter>'+
  '</wfs:Update>'+
'</wfs:Transaction>';

//Request using HttpCLient

let doc = parser.parseFromString(xmlData, "application/xml");

let headers = new HttpHeaders()
.set("Authorization", btoa("admin:geoserver"))
.set('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*')
.set('Content-Type', 'application/xml');
this.httpClient.post(this.ENDPOINT + 'geoserver/workspace/wfs', doc, {headers: headers, 
withCredentials : true, observe : 'body'})
.subscribe((rs) => {
console.error(rs);
})

//Request using HTTP

this.httpNative.post(this.ENDPOINT + 'geoserver/workspace/wfs',xmlData , {
Authorization: btoa("admin:geoserver"), 'Content-Type': 'application/xml',
}
).then((rs) => {
console.log(rs);
}).catch((err) => {
console.error(err);
})
```

Need help to solve it.

Comment: You need to verify that your server is returing right CORS headers. Since ionic app runs on a WebView, CORS policy is enforced by the underlying WebView browser. Here is a detailed answer on CORS errors in Ionic: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59961365/10602679

Comment: If you don't have access to Server, then you can use HttpAdvance plugin for ionic that performs native call.

Comment: Thanks a lot. But I also use HttpAdvance but it doesn't recognize the Xml object. I get this error when I try `"org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserException: only whitespace content allowed before start tag and not [ (position: START_DOCUMENT seen [... @1:1) 
only whitespace content allowed before start tag and not [ (position: START_DOCUMENT seen [... @1:1) `

Comment: Have you tried setting the setDataSerializer() property of HTTPAdvance?? You can try to set it to 'multi-part' or 'utf-8'. Read the documentation of HTTPAdvance here:https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-plugin-advanced-http

Comment: Yes, I've tried but it doesn't work.

Comment: Send the data in parenthesis this.httpNative.post(api, {doc},{headers})

Comment: Thanks a lot guy, I've found a solution. I've finally used HTTPAdvance then set the `Content-type` to `plain/text` and the `dataSerialize` to `ut8`. It works fine. I didn't need to put the String in parenthesis neither in bracket. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
    let headers = {
      // Specifying that we will send XML.
      "Content-type": 'text/xml;charset="utf-8"',

      // Specifying that we will except XML.
      "Accept": "text/xml",
    };

    // Setting the data serializer as "utf8" is very important so that
    // the HTTP will know that the body will not be a JSON object, but
    // a unicoded string which is the XML.
    this.http.setDataSerializer("utf8");
    
    let xmlString = '<wfs:Transaction service="WFS" version="1.0.0" ' +
      'xmlns:topp="http://www.openplans.org/topp" ' +
      'xmlns:ogc="http://www.opengis.net/ogc" ' +
      'xmlns:wfs="http://www.opengis.net/wfs">' +
      '<wfs:Update typeName="topp:tasmania_roads">' +
      '<wfs:Property>' +
      '<wfs:Name>TYPE</wfs:Name>' +
      '<wfs:Value>street</wfs:Value>' +
      '</wfs:Property>' +
      '<ogc:Filter>' +
      '<ogc:FeatureId fid="tasmania_roads.1"/>' +
      '</ogc:Filter>' +
      '</wfs:Update>' +
      '</wfs:Transaction>';

    this.http.post('https://...', xmlString, headers).then(response => {

      console.log("Response", response);
      console.log("Response Data", response.data);
    }).catch(error => {
      console.log(error);
    });
```